# Make a file drop immutable, linux

Tags: linux, centos, centos-6

I'm trying to install a custombuild on my VPS. I got the file on it but the only problem is that I can't execute it. When I execute it an error message appears; "Cannot open: Permission denied". The first time I saw this I searched on how I could change the permissions. I found out that I could do it with chmod, but when I used it I got the error "Permission denied". So I looked up a few things about it and there was something about "immutable". I'm not completely sure what to do right now or how I can fix this.

Does anyone have an idea how I can fix it or have some information for me about this subject.

p.s. This is the first time I'm doing something with linux, so I don't realy know much about it.

Answer (score 1):

Do you actually have permission to do what you want?
If you want to remove immutable bit try chattr -i from root.

Comment: I also can't do that, I get a message that I don't have permission. The exact line that I get is: Operation not permitted while setting flags on ........